# Open unit disk $\cup$ half its boundary is not homeomorphic to an open set in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let's say we have an open disk, and we add half its boundary to it. That is, if this disk is centered at the origin, then we have a semi-circular arc around it, starting from $(-1,0)$ and going to $(1,0)$. Let's call this shape $S$. How do we show that $S$ is not homeomorphic to an open set in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$? I know the problematic part is the segment of the boundary, but I'm not able to show this.

Note that $S$ is not a compact set, so the argument that a homeomorphism takes a compact set to a compact set, which is used to show that the closed disk is not homeomorphic to an open set in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is not what I'm missing here.

Edit: How is this for a solution?

For contradiction, let $\varphi$ be such a homeomorphism. Then $\varphi(S) = \varphi(S_{0}) \cup \varphi(S_{1})$, where $S_{0}$ is the open unit disk and $S_{1}$ is the arc I'm adding. Furthermore, we know that $\varphi(S_{0})$ and $\varphi(S_{1})$ are disjoint since $S_{0}$ and $S_{1}$ are disjoint. Since $S_{1}$ is not open in $S$, $\varphi(S_{1})$ is not open in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, and so $\varphi(S_{1}) \cup \varphi(S_{2}) = \varphi(S)$ is not open in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ (note the disjointness), which is a contradiction.

Comment: Open disk without a point is not simply connected. On the other hand $S$ without a point on the arc is still simply connected.

Answer (score 3):

You can remove a closed arc (the one you added) from $S$ and have it remain connected and simply connected, but that’s not true for the open disk.

Answer (score 1):

A union of an open and a non-open disjoint set can be open. Consider the union of an open disk with a half-open ring (closed on the inside, open on the outside) which give a larger open disk. So your argumentation is wrong.

One way of solving this is to show that the open disk loses the property of being simply connected if we remove one point from it, which is not true for the set $S$. If we remove a point $p$ on the arc from $S$ then $S\setminus \{p\}$ is still simply connected. And of course homomorphisms preserve simple connectedness.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your example of the disjoint sets (open and non open) whose union is open. What is a half-open ring?

Comment: @gtoques : He means the region between two concentric circles, including the inner boundary circle but not the outer one (hence "half-open"). So when you throw in the inner open disk, it "fills in" the hole and you get the entire larger open disk, which is open.

Comment: I think he's talking about a set of the form $\{(x,y)\mid a \leq x^2 + y^2 < b\}$. Note that this set forms a ring which contains its inner boundary (where $x^2 + y^2 = a$), and doesn't contain its outer boundary (where $x^2+y^2=b$).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. That is exactly what I meant. We have $\{(x,y) | x^2 + y^2 < a\}  \cup \{(x,y) | a \leq x^2+y^2 < b\}= \{(x,y) | x^2 + y^2 < b\}$, the first two being open and non-open disjoint sets, and their union an open set.